Not the same sys.path in a shell and in Spyder
Why isn't the sys.path in Spyder the same as in a shell?
In a shell, python -c "import sys ; print(sys.path)" doesn't give the same thing as if I stop the script at the first line with a breakpoint to do in the debugging console import sys ; print(sys.path).
I've managed to get around the issue by defining the necessary directories in Tools > PYTHONPATH Manager, but I find the method rather dirty as the sys.path is correct outside Spyder ...
Edit
Some results :
1- On the host:
1-1 In a shell (where the IDE will be started, so with the same environment):
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$ python -c "import sys; print('\nsys.path:' + '\n- '.join(sys.path)); print('\nsys.executable: ', sys.executable, '\n')"

sys.path:
- /usr/lib64/python312.zip
- /usr/lib64/python3.12
- /usr/lib64/python3.12/lib-dynload
- /home/toto/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages
- /usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages
- /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages

sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python

1-1 In Spyder:
IPdb [8]: print('\nsys.path:\n' + '\n'.join(f'- {path}' for path in sys.path))

sys.path:
- /usr/lib64/python312.zip
- /usr/lib64/python3.12
- /usr/lib64/python3.12/lib-dynload
- 
- /home/toto/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages
- /usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages
- /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages
- /data/Git_projects

IPdb [9]: print('\nsys.executable: ', sys.executable)

sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python

So we have the same thing (with the project path in the last position, which is configured in Spyder). Sounds perfect to me.
2- On a singularity container:
2-1 In a shell (where the IDE will be started, so with the same environment):
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/casa/host/src/development/brainvisa-cmake/master/python:/casa/host/build/python

$ python -c "import sys; print('\nsys.path:' + '\n- '.join(sys.path)); print('\nsys.executable: ', sys.executable, '\n')"

sys.path:
- /casa/host/src/development/brainvisa-cmake/master/python
- /casa/host/build/python
- /usr/lib/python310.zip
- /usr/lib/python3.10
- /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
- /casa/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
- /casa/host/src/populse/populse_db/master/python
- /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
- /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/DracoPy-1.3.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg
- /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
- /usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
- /casa/host/build/python/sitecustomize
- /casa/host/src/development/casa-distro/master/python
- /casa/host/src/capsul/master

sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python 

2-2 In Spyder:
IPdb [2]: print('\nsys.path:\n' + '\n'.join(f'- {path}' for path in sys.path))

sys.path:
- /usr/lib/python310.zip
- /usr/lib/python3.10
- /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
- 
- /casa/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
- /casa/host/src/populse/populse_db/master/python
- /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
- /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/DracoPy-1.3.0-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg
- /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
- /usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
- /casa/home/Git_projects

IPdb [3]: print('\nsys.executable: ', sys.executable)

sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python

We notice that we've lost the last 3 elements of sys.path in Spyder.

/casa/host/build/python/sitecustomize
/casa/host/src/development/casa-distro/master/python
/casa/host/src/capsul/master

I would like to point out that these are paths that we define elsewhere in the container, but these paths are well known in the environment (what I call shell, which is a bit too simplistic) as shown in 2-1. It seems to me that Spyder should be able to retrieve the latter elements by default...
However, it's true that all is not lost, because as I wrote above, it is possible to define a Spyder-specific PYTHONPATH with these elements... It's just that I don't think developers really want to waste time with these configuration steps.

Probably because Spyder is configured to use a different version of Python.

Possibly because Spyder's has a customized path configuration

why do you want the same sys.path ? It seems Spyder needs different sys.path for some reason. And if you need some path then sys.path is a list and you can do sys.path.append(). And if you don't need some path then you can remove element from list. But this can make problem if you remove important path. As for me  it waste of time to changing it.

you should check sys.executable to see what Python is used in Spyder. Probably somewhere in setting you may have option to assign different Python to project.

@JohnGordon, before asking stackoverflow for help, I obviously tried to figure it out on my own and tested it by explicitly specifying the path to the python to use in the Spyder configuration. If I remember correctly, I also looked at what sys.executable gives in spyder ... I'm working on several stations and won't have my hands on the station in question until next Friday. I'll be checking it next Friday anyway ...

@inspectorG4dget, sure, that's exactly what I'd like to understand.

@furas, I simply think that an IDE (I regularly use Pycharm and Liclipse and have never observed this type of problem with these two IDEs. I confess I've just started testing Spyder and don't know it very well yet!) should by default use the sys.path of the environment in which this IDE is launched ... Then, it should be possible to change the sys.path, in the IDE configuration, I think that's a good option, but not the other way around.

@furas, Then, manipulating the sys.path directly in the code, we already do that, but if I use an IDE it's mainly for debugging and I think that in this case we want to work on the raw code without modifying it to manipulate the sys.path ...

Please update the question and add the contents of sys.path for both cases.

IDEs often allow developers to manipulate environment variables in the runtime. I know that Eclipse and PyCharm (IDEs that I've used) allow developers to set various environment variables, which then become accessible to the code. These environment variables include PATH and PYTHONPATH (the latter of which is sys.path).
Typically, IDEs will inherit sys.path from whatever they think the system python is (or more specifically, whatever python you point them to). The previous sentence was intentionally worded somewhat weirdly, because "what they think the system python is" could be easily changed by something like pyenv or virtual environments.

Typically, IDEs will inherit sys.path from

That's typically. You could also manipulate that path by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable in your IDE.
You could further manipulate that with sys.path.append(...) -- it's just a python list.
There's another important variable in your question, and that is "what do you mean by shell?". My guess is that you meant "invoking a python REPL in any terminal outside of the Spyder IDE". Assuming that you're using the same python (confirm with sys.executable), we're left with environment variables.
On the other hand, if you were talking about os.system(...), subprocess.Popen(...), or subprocess.check_call(...), etc, these library functions often expose an API to inject environment variables into their invocation.
So, "why does the shell python have a different sys.path than Spyder python?"
Because of any of the following reasons

PYTHONPATH set in environment variables or .env
manipulation by virtual environments or pyenv
sys.path manipulation in code
Shell environment manipulation in python, while using os or subprocess


Thanks @inspectorG4dget for pointing this out.  When I speak of a shell, I'm referring to the environment in a given state (for example, directly on the host or in a container). The IDE's ability to modify environment parameters (PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc.) seems to me to be a good thing. However, it seems to me that an IDE should retrieve these default environment variables at startup, to enable the developer to work in the IDE under the same conditions as in the environment where the IDE was started.

In my opinion, in a shell (i.e. in a given environment), if I do $ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)", I think we should get the same result in the IDE... That was the point of my question, for Pycharm it seems to be the case and a priori not for Spyder.

I'll modify my question to include the value of the requested objects.

@servoz, not the case for all IDEs (particularly not the ones that let you configure a Python runtime within them), and doubly not the case for IDEs that you launch from your GUI and not from your shell (so they have a different parent process that hasn't run your shell dotfiles at all and picked up environment variables configured therein).

@Charles Duffy, I never thought of this before, so thanks for pointing them out to me. However, don't you think that in the case of starting the IDE from a CLI (e.g. a shell) and setting the same python runtime in the IDE, the sys.path (which is crucial in python) should be identical to what would be found in the shell?

@servoz, in practice, nope, not at all.

@servoz, ...I mean, this depends on what you're doing in your dotfiles, but in my dotfiles I'm often setting up things like nix (my preference) or macports (worse) or homebrew (even worse than that). Something I start from a GUI won't see that setup at all unless I do extra configuration (which is possible but OS-specific; very different between MacOS and Linux f/e), so I expect things I start from the GUI in MacOS to use Apple's default Python interpreter, whereas things I start from a shell see the Nix-provided one.

25 years ago, Linux ran your X11 parent process as a child of your login shell so everything your desktop environment started saw variables you set in your .profile, but that hasn't been true for a while now.
